# 4-channel MOSFET amplifier module

Tags: mosfet

I have a 4-channel N-MOSFET opto-isolated amplifier module to relay tail brake lights to car trailer lights.

My question is not with the module but the brake light input to the module. This has CAN bus monitoring for cruise control brake switching bulb monitoring.

I get 4 V on the brake wire when the side lights are on and 8 V when the ignition is on. This is apparently normal for my car.

The problem is these voltages are enough to switch the opto-isolator on when not required. I want to discriminate from these until the brakes are activated and the wire goes to 12 V.

I have used an op-amp LM740 comparator but I still get residual voltage that triggers the opto-isolator. I have used an 2N7000 N-MOSFET with a potential divider to the gate and that works, but that switches low and I need it to go high 12 V.

So could I use a P-channel MOSFET and an N-channel MOSFET to switch high to the module to get over this? This only has to drive the opto-isolator and a monitoring LED, so not much load at all.

The gate input R<sub>ds(on)</sub> has to draw very little current; I don't want to upset the CAN bus cruise control.

I hope someone has a simple solution.

Comment: "2N7000 N-MOSFET with a potential divider to the gate and that works"  then two cascaded will give the correct polarity is one way.

Comment: Thanks Tony I saw a circuit I could use on this subject. Not tried a double nchannel so thanks. If it solves my problem I,ll let you know. Why they use computers to do simple stuff is always to get more money for repairs